# How Can I Adjust My Cape Manager to Not Get Runtime Errors on the BeagleBone Black?

Tags: python, linux, debian, beagleboneblack, led

I noticed that I keep getting a "**Runtime Error: Problem with Cape Manager**" when I run a specific piece of software on my **BeagleBone Black**. I have a RGB LED with four wires coming out of it and they are connected to my BBB via resistors and jumper wires. How does my cape manager work and where can I find this information? Where can I find info. on how to change the **Cape Manager** and why would need to change the **Cape Manager**? The software is listed here:

```
import Adafruit_BBIO.PWM as PWM
import time

red = "P8_13"
green = "P8_19"
blue = "P9_14"

PWM.start(red, 0)
PWM.start(blue, 0)
PWM.start(green, 0)

def fade(colorA, colorB, ignore_color):
    PWM.set_duty_cycle(ignore_color, 100)
    for i in range(0, 100):
        PWM.set_duty_cycle(colorA, i)
        PWM.set_duty_cycle(colorB, 100-i)
        time.sleep(0.05)

while True:
    fade(red, green, blue)
    fade(green, blue, red)
    fade(blue, red, green)
```

Now...

I am running a Python program from Adafruit's website listed under their BeagleBone Black section of their site.

I can change the **/boot** directory file **uEnv.txt** and get my software to work but when I reboot, the system does not arrive to be. It ceases. I cannot boot.

Is there a way to run this software after changing my **/boot/uEnv.txt** file and what would I need to change?

Seth

P.S. I am running a BeagleBoard.org Debian Image 2017-04-16. **uname -a** on the cmd line states: Linux beaglebone 4.4.61-ti-r98.

Comment: Simon Monk wrote this software for the BBB in Python with the Adafruit_BBIO and it was updated in 2015 on Adafruit's website. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Cape Manager is a thing of the past. u-boot overlays is used now and the sysfs and chardev directories are used instead.